# Ignore specific tag in HTML in Android

Tags: java, android, html, regex

I have this parsed content:

```
<div id=\"spArticleColumn\" score=\"55.0\">\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t<div id=\"spArticleTopAsset\" score=\"40.0\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\n<div class=\"spArticleImageBox spAssetAligncenter\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/bild-859871-409806.html\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<img src=\"http://cdn3.spiegel.de/images/image-409806-panoV9free-jzco.jpg\" width=\"520\" border=\"0\" class=\"spPanoImageTeaserPic\" title=\"Peer Steinbrück: Vorträge waren mit mindestens 7000 Euro vergütet\" alt=\"Peer Steinbrück: Vorträge waren mit mindestens 7000 Euro vergütet\"></span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\n</div>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n<div id=\"spFbTwitterBarStd\" score=\"1.25\">\n\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t</div>\n<div id=\"spArticleSection\">\n\t\n<p>Hamburg<b> -</b> Nach Informationen des SPIEGEL pflegte der SPD-Kanzlerkandidat Steinbrück eine größere Nähe zu Bankenlobbyisten und einer Wirtschaftskanzlei als bisher bekannt. Diese durften in seiner Zeit als Bundesfinanzminister die Gründung einer halbstaatlichen Beratungsfirma für Public-Private-Partnership-Modelle vorbereiten - später hielt Steinbrück bei einigen der beteiligten Firmen bezahlte Vorträge.</p>\n\n<p>\n\n\tDie Lobbyorganisation Initiative Finanzstandort Deutschland erarbeitete 2007 das Konzept für diese Beratungsfirma (ÖPP Deutschland AG), das Rechtsgutachten lieferte die Wirtschaftskanzlei Freshfields Bruckhaus Deringer; Steinbrück stimmte dem Konzept zu, das Finanzministerium beteiligte sich später mit rund 50 Prozent an der ÖPP Deutschland AG. Nach seinem Ausscheiden aus dem Ministerium trat Steinbrück sowohl bei Freshfields Bruckhaus Deringer als auch bei mehreren beteiligten Finanzinstituten wie der Deutschen Bank und der Landesbank Hessen-Thüringen als Redner auf - vergütet mit jeweils mindestens 7000 Euro.</p>\n\n<p>Auch von der Automatenwirtschaft, die Lobbyarbeit für Spielcasinos betreibt, ließ sich Steinbrück engagieren. Im Herbst 2010 trat er bei Feierlichkeiten zum 20-jährigen Jubiläum des \"Forums für Automatenunternehmer in Europa\" auf. Auf der Liste seiner Nebentätigkeiten ist als Auftraggeber nur eine Forum Marketing-Service GmbH in Berlin genannt; sie gehört der Automatenwirtschaft.</p>\n\n<p>Steinbrück hatte am Freitag nach massivem öffentlichen Druck plötzlich angekündigt, <a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/debatte-um-nebeneinkuenfte-peer-steinbrueck-beugt-sich-der-kritik-a-859705.html\" title=\"alle Informationen zu seinen Honoraren so schnell und umfassend wie möglich offen zu legen\" class=\"spTextlinkInt\">alle Informationen zu seinen Honoraren so schnell und umfassend wie möglich offen zu legen</a>. Kurz zuvor hatte er dies noch abgelehnt. Derzeit müssen Abgeordnete Nebeneinkünfte nicht konkret preisgeben, sondern lediglich drei Stufen zuordnen - bis 3500 Euro, bis 7000 Euro und mehr als 7000 Euro. Ein Abgeordneter kann von einem Auftraggeber also wesentlich mehr erhalten, ohne dies öffentlich zu machen. Steinbrück hat in der laufenden Legislaturperiode mehr als 80 Vorträge gehalten, für die er Honorare der höchsten Stufe bekommen hat.</p>\n\n<p>Die Bundestagsverwaltung hat nach SPIEGEL-Informationen einen Vorschlag zur Veröffentlichung der Nebentätigkeiten von Abgeordneten erarbeitet: die bisher dreistufige Anzeigepflicht um sieben Stufen zu ergänzen. Die Abgeordneten müssten dann auch Honorare von mehr als 100.000 oder 150.000 Euro gesondert ausweisen. </p>\n\n<p>In einem Interview mit dem Deutschlandfunk hatte Steinbrück am Samstag vor den Folgen gewarnt, die die Debatte um Nebeneinkünfte von Parlamentariern auslösen könne. Bei den Wählern könnten Ressentiments bestätigt werden, dass Politiker sich in einem System der Vorteilsnahme und Selbstbereicherung bewegten. \"Da muss man aufpassen, dass man über Parteigrenzen hinweg nicht einen Prozess in Gang setzt, der die Politik insgesamt beschädigt\", mahnte Steinbrück. Er glaube zudem, dass eine gewisse Privatheit gelten müsse. \"Ich glaube, dass es Transparenz nur in Diktaturen gibt\", sagte Steinbrück. Kritik an seinen bezahlten Vorträgen vor Bankern nannte Steinbrück \"dämlich\" und \"absurd\". Im Deutschlandfunk sagte er, Teilnehmer seiner Vorträge würden bestätigen können, \"dass ich alles andere als ein <a href=\"http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/steinbrueck-wettert-gegen-kritiker-kein-knecht-des-kapitals-a-859816.html\" title=\"Knecht des Kapitals\" class=\"spTextlinkInt\">Knecht des Kapitals</a> gewesen bin\".</p>\n\n<p>\n<b>Diese Meldung kommt aus dem neuen SPIEGEL. Hier können Sie das Heft ab Sonntag um acht Uhr kaufen.</b>\n</p>\n\n</div>\n\n\t\t\n\n\n<br class=\"spBreakNoHeight\" clear=\"all\"></div>\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t
```

As you can see its all just text besides of one Image in this:

```
<img src=\"http://cdn3.spiegel.de/images/image-409806-panoV9free-jzco.jpg\" width=\"520\" border=\"0\" class=\"spPanoImageTeaserPic\" title=\"Peer Steinbrück: Vorträge waren mit mindestens 7000 Euro vergütet\" alt=\"Peer Steinbrück: Vorträge waren mit mindestens 7000 Euro vergütet\">
```

I would like to set this contet to a TextView like this:

```
txt1.setText(Html.fromHtml(the content above));
```

but I can't because there is a Image in this HTML. I can't set a Image to a TextView, so Android displays a blue error box, but the rest (the text) gets displayed well.

So my question:
Can I replace the  tag and all what's in in it with regex? Or with some different method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've always been a fan of regular expression replacements for stuff like that.

if you don't have a closing tag, you should have something like:

```
htmlContent = htmlContent.replaceAll("<img.*?>", "");
```

if you do have a closing tag, use:

```
htmlContent = htmlContent.replaceAll("<img.*?>.*?</img>", "");
```

Comment: just in case there is content there it will still match. the '.' character means match ANY character. the '*' means 0 or more of that character (so ANY number of ANY character). the '?' makes it stop as soon as it finds the next character. '.*' will find everything on the line - even if you did '.*<' because '<' matches under the '.'. the second '.*?' isn't strictly necessary but i think its a good idea